# Not able to remove components in Editable Template AEM

Tags: adobe, aem, aem-touch-ui

I have been following the tutorial I have linked here to create a custom layout component https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/bootstrap_grid.html but I noticed that removing this component from an Editable Template is not possible. How should I solve my problem?

Answer (score 4):

### TLDR;

- Add content to the parsys in the component you are trying to delete (assuming it has a parsys or area to drag components to).
- Refresh the page
- Delete the structure component

### Long Term Fix

For a more long term fix, have the component in question generate the missing content using a cq:template node.

### Whats really happening

This is a bit wonky - but I'll do my best to explain.

If you are referencing content within your structure components via data-sly-resource using the @ resourceType option, you can't delete your structured component.

I just went through the ringer with this one. I had a very simple structure component:

```html
<div class="full-stack-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div data-sly-resource="${'content' @ resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/responsivegrid'}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And when I dragged it onto my editable template I could never delete it.

[image: Cant delete structure component in editable template]

When you use `@resourceType` in a rendering script and the content doesn't actually exist, it creates whats known as a **SyntheticResource**.

So in my example, I went to the JCR and there is no `content` node underneath my `content-container`:

[image: Missing content node in JCR]

If I manually create the missing `content` (because of the `data-sly-resource="${'content'` from my code above) I can then delete the component.

[image: created content node]

As you can see the delete option is now there:
[image]

For a quick fix - just drag something into the parsys to create the node.

For a more long term fix, have the component in question generate that content using a cq:template node.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this page is NOT using editable template.

- When a page has a relative path in sling:resourceType like this: 'grid-aem/components/structure/page', it is using static template.
- Editable templates are created under /conf folder.
- [More differences](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2365288) between static and editable templates.

The static template provided in the sample includes only 1 parsys component in `/apps/grid-aem/components/structure/page/partials/main.html`.

So components added within the parsys can be easily delete on the page itself using delete button:
[image]

If you are looking to remove a parsys within the colcontrol component, this is a custom colcontrol with logic implemented to change number of columns. You need to author the component with desired number of columns. For example selecting 3 columns shows 3 parsys:
[image]

Selecting 2 columns on same component shows 2 parsys like this:
[image]

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

## Listen to the `inspectable-added` event and add the `child nodes` with `Javascript`:

### STEP 1: Create a `ClientLibraryFolder` and add the `cq.authoring.dialog.all` category:

[image]

### STEP 2: Write `Javascript` to listen to the `inspectable-added` event.  The `callback function` should add the `child-nodes` to the `editable-template` that are needed for the component to have all functionality such as `EDIT, DELETE, MOVE, COPY` etc.

```
(function($document, $) {
  $document.on('cq-inspectable-added', cb_inspectableAdded);
  function cb_inspectableAdded(evt) {
    try {
        var inspectable = evt.inspectable;
        var ajaxConfig = {
            url: evt.inspectable.path,
            data: {
                'sling:resourceType': inspectable.type
            },
            async: false    
        };

        if(inspectable.type.indexOf('myApp/components') > -1) $.post(ajaxConfig); //  replace myApp/components with your partial-path
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }   
  }
}($(document), jQuery));
```

That's it! Now, when you add a component which has nested components such as a `custom-layout-container` or `parsys` or `custom components-inside-components`; it should have all the functionality.

Good Luck...